# Play framework 2 tag compilation error

Tags: frameworks, tags, playframework-2.0, helper

I am new to Play framework 2 and I am trying to implement a simple tag supported by a Java class.
But I can not get working because I am getting a compilation error

compilation error on the browser
illegal start of simple expression
In \app\views\tags\security.scala.html at line 3.

tag file
views/tags/security.scala.html

```
@(roles:String)(body:Html)
@import helpers.SecurityHelper._
@if(restricted (@session().get("roles"),@roles)==true){
@body
}
```

Helper class code
    package helpers;

```
public class SecurityHelper {
    public static boolean restricted(String userRoles, String ressourceRoles) {
        String[] roles = userRoles.split("_");
        boolean b = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
            if (roles[i].indexOf(ressourceRoles) != -1) {
                b = true;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

how I want to use it:
in my other template, I call the tag as follow:

```
@security("job-view"){
Welcome
}
```

I can't figure out the problem, any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need write next first line of html-file:

```
@(roles:String, body:Html)(implicit session: Session)
```

and not "@session" in if-statement, "session" enough

but I need more information about errors